# Unable to volume mount in datastax enterprise server container

Tags: docker, datastax-enterprise

Am unable to install DSE enterprise server using the docker path

Following instructions from here. https://hub.docker.com/r/datastax/dse-server/. I wanted to mount a host volume, so I don't lose data. so started mounting volumes listed under Volumes and data of the link.

Running it so :

```
docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept -p 8182:8182 \
    -v /Users/sseshac/src/dse/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra \
    --name my-dse -d datastax/dse-server -s -k -g
```

However I end up getting these errors.
Am pretty sure host has access to `/Users/sseshac/src/dse/cassandra` and the directory exists. However I end up seeing this in container logs

```
1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: commitlog directory '/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
```

I viewed Dockerfile from dockerhub and did also try creating a user in y Mac and manually setting its userid to 999, but in vain. Is the documentation missing some information or am I doing it wrong ?

Any help in pointing any missing step will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolved it, if so how. I have tried creating a dse user and changed the owner to dse on host machine but still no luck.